# Почему появляется горизонтальная полоса прокрутки?

Tags: html, css

```
.s1{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 85vw;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 15vw;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: brown;
}
```

Горизонтальная полоса прокрутки появляется при ненулевом значении top у класса s1. Как убрать?

Comment: Непонятно, зачем вам это нужно? ну а вообще `left:15vw;`, убрать и все норм. - Но опять-же, не понятно, зачем вам это, что вы пытаетесь добиться от этого.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Горизонтальная полоса прокрутки появляется при ненулевом значении top

Когда блок 100% высоты и 100% ширины сдвигается вниз, сначала появится вертикальная прокрутка.
А вот появление вертикальной прокрутки - уже не даст Вам отобразить блок на 100% в ширину (так как полоса прокрутки займет определенную ширину), и тогда появится горизонтальная полоса прокрутки.

Для решения нужно установить запрет отображения полосы прокрутки для одного из родительских блоков с классом s1, или сразу для всего body

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```